# SQL Query - Eliminate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data is stored in the format below, parent code can have zero or more child. The status of Parent and Child is shown. The question is, using SQL query can we eliminate only the parent whose status and child status is closed. For e.g. for the example below only P1 and p4 needs to be eliminated.

```
ParentCode ChildCode ParentStatus ChildStatus
P1           0         Closed       Closed
P1           C1        Closed       Closed
P2           0         Closed       Closed
P2           C2        Closed       Open
P3           0         Open         Closed
P3           C3        Open         Open
P4           0         Closed       Closed
P5           0         Open         Closed
```

Comment: What is you RDBMS, please? (Oracle, MS Sql, MySql etc)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko its MS SQL

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih, the expected result is a little complex Union of Parent and Child Code which is P2,C2, P3, C3, P5

Comment: @AndyKash Would you want to display the result as one row and connect those name with a comma?

Comment: @D-Shih, sorry just in column format

p2
c2
p3
c3
p5

Comment: @AndyKash OK I edit my answer you can try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You can try to use `not exists` subquery to eliminated.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T t1
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from T tt 
    where tt.ParentStatus = t1.ParentStatus and tt.ParentStatus = 'Closed'
    and tt.ChildStatus = t1.ChildStatus and tt.ChildStatus = 'Closed'
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b9ce3fcf7fa3e108c4aa50e776825689)

**EDIT**

You can try to use `CTE` with `distinct` to make your expectation from your comment,

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM T t1
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from T tt 
        where tt.ParentStatus = t1.ParentStatus and tt.ParentStatus = 'Closed'
        and tt.ChildStatus = t1.ChildStatus and tt.ChildStatus = 'Closed'
    )
),CTE2 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT code
    FROM (
        SELECT ChildCode code
        FROM CTE 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ParentCode
        FROM CTE 
    ) t1
    WHERE code <> '0'
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a292839c310ec4ccb2b69b7fe92701b0)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query,

```
select * from Table
where ParentStatus <> 'Closed' OR ChildStatus <> 'Closed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simple aggregation works with this data structure:

```
select parentcode
from t
group by parentcode
having min(ParentStatus) = max(ParentStatus) and
       min(ParentStatus) = 'Closed' and
       min(ChildStatus) = max(ChildStatus) and
       min(ChildStatus) = 'Closed' ;
```